# Accepting a string from a Qt dialog box

Tags: c++, qt

I want to accept a string into my main.cpp from a Qt dialog box when the "OK" Button is pressed. I haven't been able to figure out how the signals/slots work as the documentation and tutorials seem mostly non-existent.

So far the only tutorial I have found that works is this:
https://netbeans.org/kb/72/cnd/qt-applications.html

Which is roughly all I have.

Comment: None-existent? How come? http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/signalsandslots.html#a-small-example. Btw, only `QObject` and it's derivatives can process signals/slots so it's better accept the string somewhere else other than in main.

Comment: @Tay2510 In [Qt5 you can connect signals to regular functions](http://qt-project.org/wiki/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax#2f49cd0d473b52e6ddb8b377a34e6c36).

Comment: @thuga Thanks for the info. I am a Qt4 user and never know it!

Comment: The documentation has always been very good. Perhaps you weren't reading the official reference.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to read a single string, you can use [`QInputDialog::getText`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qinputdialog.html#getText).

Here is the example code that they provide:

```
bool ok;
QString text = QInputDialog::getText(this, tr("QInputDialog::getText()"),
                                     tr("User name:"), QLineEdit::Normal,
                                     QDir::home().dirName(), &ok);
if (ok && !text.isEmpty())
     textLabel->setText(text);
```